# When to use SAT vs solving?

Tags: satisfiability, sat-solvers, smt-solvers

Are there any guidelines for how to recognize, for a given problem, which approach is more likely to yield good results? SAT solver or SMT solver?
Is there any guidance anyone can offer about which sorts of problems can be handled better by SAT solvers than by SMT solvers, or vice versa?

Comment: There are a variety of solvers. But no one knows which will give better result. No one even knows why oftenly SAT is solved fast (except cases when you pick first  two literals in each clause and solve given 2-SAT and it's satisfiable).

Comment: What does this question mean? Eager SMT vs lazy? Or literally SAT vs SMT (in which case how does it make sense? they solve different problems)

Comment: See https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12325/755 and https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12087/755 for some related discussion.