# Covering grid with constrained rectangles

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I need to place N rects on a 2-dimensional grid with constraints.

For the each rect height/width and placing limitations($x_{min}$-$x_{max}$) are known.

The problem is to place all rects on a grid with no intersections that every rect's bottom left $x$ is in rect's $x_{min}$-$x_{max}$.

I've implemented the naive solution where I just iterating over rects and incrementing $x$ by some fixed step while checking for intersections. If no place found then I increment $y$ and iterate again.

The question: I'm sure that there are algorithms/data structures that will help me to solve this task faster, but I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a constraint solver, like [Minion](http://minion.sourceforge.net/).  The following paper shows that they are effective for a related problem:

- [Almost Square Packing](http://4c.ucc.ie/~hsimonis/almostsquarepacking.pdf), Helmut Simonis and Barry O’Sullivan.

My thanks to András Salamon for [pointing to this information](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/12123/755).

You could also try using a SAT solver.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Constraint solver really seems like the best option here